# Migrating specific nodes from Drupal 6 to Drupal 7

Tags: migrations

I have an existing Drupal 6 site, and an updated version of the same site running on Drupal 7. Setting up the Drupal 7 site did take a lot longer than I planned, and the old Drupal 6 site accumulated some more content in the meantime. I now want to migrate some new nodes from the old site to the new one, but not all of them as many already exist on the new site in updated versions.

I did find the Migrate module, but from what I can tell this seems to be a framework, and not an out of the box solution.

Is there an easy way to migrate specific nodes, either hand-picked or based on selection criteria like node type and creation date, between two Drupal installations of different major versions?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I know is export your nodes from Drupal 6 by using [Node Export](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_export) . Then you can import your node to Drupal 7 by [Feeds](https://www.drupal.org/project/feeds) module. This has update and replace exsisting nodes options. Just make sure you set one of the source as an "Unique" on Mapping setting, like "uid" or "title" of the node. Hope this help

Answer (score 0):

Migrate module.
We migrated an entire site using this module and migrating nodes was the easiest. The documentation is pretty well written. Let me know if you decide to go down that path. I could maybe help get you setup.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "no". But in the realm of non-easy ways, you might try

- depending on the number of the nodes in question, is recreating them by hand possible?
- if it's an option to re-run your original upgrade process on the new snapshot of the site, that might be the easiest way.  If that might be destructive to things you've created on the D7 site, try diving into the Features module for how to move site-building elements between sites.  It's work, but it builds character.
- I would investigate Node Export and Feeds next, as H-L suggested.
- Migrate and migrate_d2d are very effective tools written for a developer audience.  This will solve your problem very quickly, however if it's your first time using it, it will take a little while to get up to speed on the framework.